# Argument count variable inside a double parenthesis construct in bash

Tags: bash

From what I've read at tldp.org, the double parenthesis construct `(( ... ))` allows you to reference bash variables without the `$` prefix. However, when attempting to reference the argument count variable `$#`, the script refuses to work with a

```
bash: ((: i < # : syntax error: operand expected (error token is "# ")
```

oddly enough, when the hash is prefixed, **the script works fine**.

For your reference, here's the working code:

```
fun(){
    i=0
    while (( i < $# )); do
            echo $1;
            shift
    done
}
```

My question is: How do I know when it is correct to include the prefix and when it is not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can forgo the `$` as long as it's not a [SPECIAL PARAMETER](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Special-Parameters).  Also, if you are doing [PARAMETER EXPANSION](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion) inside `(( ))` you also need the `$`

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. Do you know where I can find better documentation regarding the `(( ))` construct?